# I would like to edit the legacy code of an Access file but I couldn't find where the VBA code is hidden in

Tags: ms-access

Hi I would like to edit the legacy code of an Access file but I couldn't find where the VBA code is hidden in.

When I clicked on "Enable Content" underneath the ribbon, the ribbon disappeared and only the GUI form is shown.

I tried to find the VBA code source but I couldn't locate it.

Kindly assist to advise thanks!

Comment: I've attached a screenshot of the Access ribbon

https://i.pinimg.com/originals/16/ac/3b/16ac3b2df25de6dcd7d9db87b7937b52.png

Comment: The question is whether the file is a `*.mdb` or `*.accdb` or whether it is a `*.mde` or `*.accde`. In the latter case you have a compiled version where the VBA source code has been removed.

Comment: i see thanks Olivier, the different file extensions of Access now makes more sense, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you hold down the shift key and keep holding it and click on the file. It will open in developer mode.  After that you press  alt-key and keep holding it snd press F11. The vba code will reveal.